# Google Sign In in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-signin

**//I have problem in Sign in with Google App crashes when Sign in , i just wanted to fetch data from Sign in and send to another activty i.e Pic.java , But it crashes please let me know where to place give code to fix this code**,I have placed code under gsignIn().

```
package app.pack.name;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    SignInButton signIn_btn;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    boolean loggedIn;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    String name,email;
    ProgressDialog progress_dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);

        name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
        email = sharedPreferences.getString("e_mail", "");
        String ID = sharedPreferences.getString("ID", "");
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin", false);



        buidNewGoogleApiClient();
        customizeSignBtn();
        setBtnClickListeners();
        progress_dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress_dialog.setMessage("Signing in....");



    }

    /*
    Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile.
    User's ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    create and  initialize GoogleApiClient object to use Google  Sign-In API and the options specified by gso..
    */

    private void buidNewGoogleApiClient(){

        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this )
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    /*
      Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
      multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
      rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
      be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
      may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
      Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN scope to see the  difference.
    */

    private void customizeSignBtn(){

        signIn_btn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signIn_btn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signIn_btn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    }

    /*
      Set on click Listeners on the sign-in sign-out and disconnect buttons
     */

    private void setBtnClickListeners(){
        // Button listeners
        signIn_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }



    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                progress_dialog.dismiss();

            }
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            getSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "start sign process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gSignIn();



                break;
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Sign Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gSignOut();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Access Revoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gRevokeAccess();
                break;

            case R.id.day_id:
                Intent  intent = new Intent(Login.this,Camera.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.day_ids:
                Intent  intents = new Intent(Login.this,Camera.class);
                startActivity(intents);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void gSignIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        progress_dialog.show();

        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //  String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

        String combine = name + "~" + tMgr.getLine1Number() + "~" + email;

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Pic.class);

        //Create the bundle
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        //Add your data to bundle
        bundle.putString("combine_data", combine);
        //  bundle.putString("combine_data2",email);

        //Add the bundle to the intent
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        //Fire that second activity
        startActivity(i);

        finish();

    }

    private void gSignOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        updateUI(false);

                    }
                });



    }

    private void gRevokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        updateUI(false);

                    }
                });
    }


    private void getSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {



            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            String id_token = acct.getIdToken(); //add this code here to save it by use SharedPreferences

            TextView user_name= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
            TextView email_id= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailId);
            user_name.setText("UserName: "+ acct.getDisplayName());
            email_id.setText("Email Id: " + acct.getEmail());
            updateUI(true);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);

             editor.putString("name", acct.getDisplayName());
            editor.putString("e_mail", acct.getEmail());
            editor.putString("ID", acct.getIdToken());
            editor.commit();

            progress_dialog.dismiss();




        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }



    }


    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }



}
```

//xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_and_disconnect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">



          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" user name:"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="email id:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Google Sign out"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/disconnect_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="revoke Google Access"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">




        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/day_id"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/day_form"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/day_ids"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/day_form"/>

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

//logcat

```
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: app.pack.app.pack.name, PID: 7755
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.pack.app.pack.name/app.pack.app.pack.name.Pic}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.pack.app.pack.name.Pic.onCreate(Pic.java:33)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 7755-7755/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-22 17:39:45.160 26263-26442/? I/ActivityManager: Process app.pack.app.pack.name (pid 7755) has died.
12-22 17:39:45.160 26263-26442/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2e93d7b4 u0 app.pack.app.pack.name/.Pic t38}: app died, no saved state
12-22 17:39:45.160 26263-26442/? D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: app.pack.app.pack.name activityName: app.pack.app.pack.name/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
12-22 17:39:45.160 26263-26442/? D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: app.pack.app.pack.name
12-22 17:39:45.190 26464-26464/? D/GuidanceScreen: event === app_launch
12-22 17:39:45.190 26464-26464/? D/GuidanceScreen: hiding guidance
12-22 17:39:45.190 26464-26464/? D/GuidanceScreen: hardKeyboard = 1
```

// Pic Activity

```
public class Pic extends Activity {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pic);


        //Get the bundle
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
        String stuff = bundle.getString("combine_data");
        // String sss = bundle.getString("combine_data2");


        String max[] = stuff.split("~");

        for (int i = 0; i < max[i].length(); i++)
            System.out.println("binku " + max[i]);

    }
}
```

// Below code in gSignIn() which crashed the app , but I want to pass data to another activty, so where I should place this code in this activity so that app not crashes

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //  String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

        String combine = name + "~" + tMgr.getLine1Number() + "~" + email;

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Pic.class);

        //Create the bundle
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        //Add your data to bundle
        bundle.putString("combine_data", combine);
        //  bundle.putString("combine_data2",email);

        //Add the bundle to the intent
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        //Fire that second activity
        startActivity(i);

        finish();
```

Comment: Error is from the class "app.pack.app.pack.name.Pic" during the onCreate, line 33, But i dont see u calling this class. Give us the code where the error occured, and the Pic class

Comment: post your Pic Activity please.

Comment: @MeGoodGuy  i edited that , but let me know there is no issue in Pic

Comment: @JörnBuitink edited plz chk , but no issue in Pic

Comment: **TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     

        String combine = name + "~" + tMgr.getLine1Number() + "~" + email;

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Pic.class);

        //Create the bundle
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 
        bundle.putString("combine_data", combine);
       
 
        i.putExtras(bundle);
    
        startActivity(i);

        finish();**

_This code crash app , but i need this to send data to another activity_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String stuff = bundle.getString("combine_data");
```

What if this String is empty or null ? u have to check this before this operation. But for now your error is here:

```
    String max[] = stuff.split("~");

    for (int i = 0; i < max[i].length(); i++)
        System.out.println("binku " + max[i]);
```

did u mean "i < max.length" ?

Comment: From your comment, the String "stuff" wont be null. i believe now "i < max.length" will resolve the problem

Comment: I got that but there is problem  that i got only value of  name, not email and tMgr.getLine1Number(), it is in String combine . What happend there ?

Comment: When u created the String "combine", tMgr.getLine1Number() and email were empty or null :/